# GWT. Label don't consume space when invisible

Tags: java, gwt

How to cause Label to consume space (on panel) even if it not visible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the style of the `Label` to hidden, you can do this via the [CSS visibility property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp). How you apply this style depends on how you have created your `Label`. See the [GWT documentation on applying styles](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/style.html).